# tracking user activity and errors/incorrect links

Tags: php

In my activity log in my database I'm seeing a few users recently visiting my custom '404 page not found' page. What's the best way in PHP to get the link address they were looking for including any '?' and '&' arguments on the end so I can store this too?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your operating system, I may recommend AWstats (http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).  It has many stats, including which 404 pages were attempted to be accessed.

It also has the added benefit that it is free.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the architecture you set up for 404 error handling.
If it is done via PHP Header redirects directly into your cms source code, then it is easy enough to get the information via HTTP_REFERER.

Let's say user A enters page Z that has an internal error, and in case of errors the logic of the page redirects to /not-found.html

Then in the source code of /not-found.html you can easily track down the referer via

```
<?php
    $referer = ( array_key_exists ( 'HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER ) && ! empty ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
?>
```

But it really depends on the structure of your "html output" handlers. Maybe the best solution, if not sure about what's going on, it's to use software like AWstats as it has been already suggested.